# Flex-[Embed a swf thats compiled to Fp10

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash, embed

Can anyone tell me why the following does NOT work if your source swf is compiled to FP10?
ie it DOES work if compiled to FP9.

```
public class MainShell extends Sprite {
    [Embed(source="path to my source swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    private static const bytes:Class;
    public function MainShell() {
        Loader(addChild(new Loader())).loadBytes(new bytes(), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain()));

    }
}
```

Comment: What does "does NOT work" mean?  Compiler error?  Or something else?

Comment: No compile error, and the compiled swf seems to be the right size but when you view or load the container swf it's blank! If I recompile the SOURCE swf to target FP9, it works!

Comment: Is your embedded SWF targeting the same Flash Player (and if applicable, Flex SDK) as the main SWF?

Comment: The embedded swf is compiled in the IDE targeting FP10, so not sure which subversion